# Weakly connected graph traversal from least number of nodes

Tags: graph, traversal

I've been given the following exercise: There's an unweighted, directed, weakly connected graph with n nodes (n < 1 000 000). We want to traverse the whole graph, starting from the least number of nodes. The question is: from which nodes do I start the traversals? I couldn't find any content on this particular topic. However, I managed to come up with an algorithm, but it's not efficient enough:

- I store the graph in an adjacency list (n can be too high for a two-dimensional matrix)
- I start a BFS from each node i, and store the nodes it reached in `x[i][...]` (`x = List<List<int>>`)
- I check whether any `x[i].Count == n`
- I check whether any `(x[i] union x[j]).Count == n`
- I check whether any `(x[i] union x[j] union x[k]).Count == n`
  ... So I make all possible unions of 2, 3, 4... subsets of x, and check whether its count is n.

It works all right if n is not too high, but I would need a more efficient algorithm for bigger n.

Any help is appreciated (you would make me be able to fall asleep again)! :)

Answer (score 0):

Find the nodes that do not have any incoming edges. Loop over these nodes, and for each node v, begin traversing the graph. Remember which nodes you visited (by putting them in a hash table or marking them). Stop traversing when you reach a node you have already visited.

You would need an adjacency list representation, where each node has a list of incoming and a list of outgoing edges. Then do something like this:

```
Set nodesToVisit = emptySet;
for i=1 to n:
    if incoming[i].size() == 0:
        nodesToVisit.add(i)

Set visited = emptySet;
for v in nodesToVisit:
    nodesToVisit.remove(v)
    if(v is not in visited):
        visit(v);
        visited.add(v);
        for u in outgoing[v]:
            nodesToVisit.add(u)
```